# Php Match words code not working on php 5.1.6

Tags: php, match, words

i have piece of code that works fine on my local test server but on live server for some reason it does not.
Php version on live server is 5.1.6.

```
$subject = 'random words to check';   
$terms = explode(' ', 'word1 word2 check');
$wordIndex = array_flip(preg_split('/\P{L}+/u', mb_strtolower($subject), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    if (isset($wordIndex[$term])) {
        echo "match>".$term;
    }
}
```

Comment: You really must debug more. Having several lines of code and function calls, saying it does not work is not good enough.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if possible, you might want to update your PHP version; PHP 5.1.6 is almost 4 years old, which means you're missing out on 4 years worth of feature additions/improvements and bugfixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First employ some basic debugging to discover what's happening on each system

- dump the output of mb_strtolower
- dump the output of preg_split
- dump the output of array_flip

Comment: output of preg_split is empty

Answer (score 0):

You might try replacing your preg_split with

```
$wordIndex = array_flip(str_word_count(mb_strtolower($subject), 2));
```

Though you may also need the additional 3rd parameter for str_word_count if you're working with multibyte strings